# Store Variable from CSS in JS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, themes

I’m working on a theme option for my app. The theme is stored via electron-store and gets applied to the pages in the render method. This works great when I’m styling other css elements with it.

However I’m having one page that is using canvas-gauges. AFAIK the gauge cannot be styled via CSS and I have to set the colors directly in the render method.

My question is now if I can somehow read out the colors of the current theme, store them in JS so I can then use a JS variable to load the colors onto the gauges.

Right now I have a section on my gauge page where I’m setting up the color themes just for this page but it would be more convenient to have everything stored in the themes.scss of course so I dont have to define the themes in two areas of the code.

My themes.scss

```
:root {
    --fillInactive: #7c7c7c;
}

[colorTheme = 'Blue'] {
    --fillActive: #3f77a4;
}
```

Dashboard.js:

```
const Store = window.require('electron-store');
const store = new Store();
const theme = store.get("colorTheme");

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

render() {

        let colorNeedle


        if(theme === 'Blue') {
            colorNeedle             = '#1a80d2'
        }


        return <div className="dashboard" colorTheme={theme}>
            <div className="dashboard__header">
            </div>
            <div className="dashboard__gauges">
            <RadialGauge

                colorNeedle = {colorNeedle}

            ></RadialGauge>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }

}

export default Dashboard;
```

I tried it like this:

```
const element = document.getElementById('dashboard');
const attribute = element.getAttribute('var(--fillActive)');
```

But I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

I'm just lacking the fundamentals here.. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you set your color variable like this `[colorTheme = 'Blue'] {--fillActive: #3f77a4}` ?

Comment: I handle the themes pretty much like here: https://lukelowrey.com/css-variable-theme-switcher/

Comment: Yes ok but your setting variable on nothing. You need an element with some atribute like on the blog post you linked `html[data-theme='dark']{--background-color: #fff}` . You need that `html` in front for setting variable.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I need to create a new custom css variable in my dashboard.scss, assign the var(--fillActive) to it and then read the property-value from the new custom variable?

Comment: Putting the html in front breaks my code.

Comment: You can do it that way, but the way that is show in this blog post you linked is changing theme simply by `overwriting` existing variables that are set in `:root`. He overwrites variables like this: `html[colorTheme='Blue']` set whatever variables you want, and then in on `html` tag you need to add colorTheme = 'Blue' attribute to use that css rules you set up in you `html[colorTheme='Blue']`. And i would rename your attribute to `data-theme`, So `html[data-theme='Blue']`.

Comment: Mh but the way that I implemented it works and I don’t want to change the values. I tried the link from the other answer to get the value with the querySelector and the getComputedStyle. However I can only access my variable —fillInactive from :root. The variables from my themes stay inaccessible although I can use them to style something on my dashboard.scss. Sry, as stated I’m lacking fundamentals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250470/discussion-between-sinisam-and-traxan).

Answer (score 0):

To declare a variable in CSS, come up with a name for the variable, then append two hyphens (–) as the prefix. The element here refers to any valid HTML element that has access to this CSS file.

You can check this example in W3 https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_var_js